# Self-injectivity of a trivial extension $B\ltimes Q/B$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, injective-module

Let $B$ be the ring of $2$-adic integers, and $Q$ be its field of fractions, and consider the trivial extension $R=B\ltimes (Q/B)$, that is, the set $B\times (Q/B)$ with coordinatewise addition and multiplication given by $(a,x)(b,y)=(ab, ay+bx)$.

I found this example given without justification in one of those Handbook of Algebra volumes as a self-injective ring (with other properties) that I'm interested in.

It's clearly commutative and local, since $B$ is, and it is also non-Noetherian.  **What's a good way to see it is self-injective?**

I would apply the Baer Criterion to $R_R$ if I felt confident I had foreseen all the ideals of $R$. Even then I'm not sure I see the trick to extend homomorphisms.

I've mainly been chasing this though: assume the injective hull $E=E(R_R)$ is strictly larger, and attempt to draw a contradiction.  Suppose $x\in E\setminus R$. Then since $R$ is essential in $E$, there's an $r\in R$ such that $xr\in R\setminus\{0\}$. Obviously $r$ can't be among the units of $R$.

If $x(b,q)$ is my nonzero element of $R$, and $b$ is nonzero, then it can be factored into $x(b,0)(1, \frac qb)$, and after cancelling off the unit you have $x(b,0)\in R$.

If $b=0$ you have $x(0,q)\in R$ straightaway. So that narrows things down to two cases, but I don't see what else to do.

Can I proceed from there?  Until now I suppose I haven't been using the fact that $B$ is uniserial, and that it gives $Q/B$ a special structure too. Maybe the key is there... I just haven't spotted it.

---

P. S. I found some references to papers by Sakano that seem like they might carry this as a special case, but I was unable to unearth an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key facts needed about $Q/B$ are:

(1) Every $B$-module endomorphism of $Q/B$ (in fact, every abelian group endomorphism) is of the form $z\mapsto az$ for some $a\in B$, so $B\cong\operatorname{Hom}_B(Q/B,Q/B)$ as $B$-modules by the map $a\mapsto[z\mapsto az]$. Also, more obviously, $Q/B\cong\operatorname{Hom}_B(B,Q/B)$ as $B$-modules by the map $x\mapsto[c\mapsto cx]$.

(2) $Q/B$ is injective as a $B$-module, so $\operatorname{Hom}_B(R,Q/B)$ is injective as an $R$-module.

Now define a map
$$R=B\ltimes Q/B\to \operatorname{Hom}_B(B\oplus (Q/B),Q/B)=\operatorname{Hom}_B(R,Q/B)$$
by
$$(a,x)\mapsto[(c,z)\mapsto cx+az)].$$

By (1), this is an isomorphism of $B$-modules, and a straightforward calculation shows that it is an $R$-module homomorphism. So, by (2), $R$ is injective as an $R$-module.

Comment: OK! Very educational. I can't believe I forgot the 'injective producing lemma."  It took a lot of reminding myself what the right $R$ module structure on the Hom is but I see it now. And (1) follows from the divisibility of $Q/B$ as a $B$ module, right?  It seems to me that given this proof, $B$ can be replaced with any PID. Does that sound right?

Comment: @rschwieb The first part of (2), the fact that $Q/B$ is injective, follows from the divisibility of $Q/B$, but I don't think (1) does. E.g., if you try to do this for $\mathbb{Z}$, then $\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ is much larger than $\mathbb{Z}$ (in fact, it is the profinite completion of $\mathbb{Z}$), and I don't think $\mathbb{Z}\ltimes(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ is self-injective.

Comment: Ah yeah, that part doesn't work...  Thanks for the help, though.