# Does there exists a Ring with unity other than $\mathbb{Z}_4$ such that for all non-zero non-unit elements of ring, $2x = 0$ and $x*x = 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with unity and $x+x=0$, $x \cdot x=0$ for all non-zero non unit element $x$ of $R$.

$\mathbb{Z}_4$ is one of the example of that ring. Does there exists any other ring of this type ?
If no then how can we prove that.

Comment: Actually no, $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is *not* an example, since $(-1)^2=1$ (and $-1\neq 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4$). Also $1+1=2\neq 0$.

Comment: @CaptainLama The question says $x$ is a non unit element

Comment: @CaptainLama Though -1 is not the identity, it is a [unit element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_(ring_theory)).

Comment: God, people really have to stop using "unit" to mean "invertible"... The question should probably be edited to make that clearer.

Answer (score 4):

Any field satisfies $x \cdot x =0$ and $2\cdot x=0$ for any non-unit element $x$.
Another example would be the quotient of the polynomial ring $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[X_i | i \in I ]$ modulo the ideal $\langle X_i^2 | i \in I\rangle$.

Comment: He wants $x\cdot x=0$ instead of $2x=0$ which is also satisfied by every field.

Answer (score 0):

There are a huge number of examples furnished by a construction known as the [trivial extension](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3755962/29335).

If you take an elementary abelian $2$-group $G$ whatsoever, and write $F_2$ to mean the field of $2$ elements, then $R=F_2\ltimes G$ is an example.  Firstly the ring has characteristic $2$ so the $x+x=0$ condition is trivially satisfied by all elements, and secondly because $1+G$ is the set of units and the complement $G$ is a subset that squares to zero.

Another observation is that if $R$ is assumed to be commutative, $x^2=0$ for all nonunits implies that the ring is local, and that its maximal ideal squares to zero.  The other condition then implies that the maximal ideal is a rng of characteristic $2$.